# How to get BSSID and SSID in android on Expo?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, bssid

I want to get the BSSID and SSID info of an android mobile. I am developing my application on Expo. Currently I am using `react-native-network-info` module but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

The library you are using required linking of the module. So as of now expo doesn't support linking, hence that library cant be used to extract SSID.

And according to expo-forum they still don't have any provision to extract the SSID and BSSID with their release. Check out the forum chats :

[Expo-SSID](https://forums.expo.io/t/is-there-any-way-to-get-ssid-in-expo/1199/4)

So what I would suggest is try to use the bare react native app(i.e not using expo) and install the library of `react-native-network-info` where things would work. If you are already into expo and the project is almost done, then I would recommend to eject from expo and then install the library `react-native-network-info` .

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts.